# How to vary jekyll's `site.title` on different pages?

Tags: jekyll

I want to present a different site title in different parts of my site (identified by a path prefix). The ideal setup would look like:

```
_includes/header.html contains:
<a class="site-title" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">{{ site.title }}</a>
```

with the header being included in page and post templates, and

```
_config.yml contains:
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      title: logophile
  -
    scope:
      path: "blog"
    values:
      title: (b)logophile
```

This however writes an empty string into the generated html.

Alternatives I've tried:

- In `_config.yml` use `site.title: logophile` / `site.title: (b)logophile`
- In `_config.yml` define `my_site_title: logophile` etc and use `{{ my_site_title }}` in `_includes/header.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default `title` will only change `page.title` if it's not already set. So, this will not work.

You can set default like this :

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      alternative_site_title: logophile
  -
    scope:
      path: "blog"
    values:
      alternative_site_title: (b)logophile
```

And call this variable like this :

```
<a class="site-title" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">
  {{ page.alternative_site_title }}
</a>
```

Comment: The insight I was missing seems to be that `default` sets `page`-level variables only: that means no way to modify `site.title` and also that the header include has to use `{{ page.my_site_title }}` instead of simply `{{ my_site_title }}`. When I think about what "default" means, that makes pretty good sense really: it's for setting *defaults* for values which the page might override.